# How to manually import/migrate orders & customers from Magento1 to Magento 2 database tables?

Tags: database, importexport, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, data-migration-tool

What is the best way to manually move the orders and customers to Magento 2.2.6 from Magento 1.8.1 without any third part extensions? there are around 100 records only.

I was able to migrated all the data and setting initially from the "clone" version of the live Magento 1 database to fresh Magento 2 database last month using the data-migration-tool. Now the magento 2 site is ready, i need to migrate the new orders and customer (for the past month, around ~50 records) to the Magento 2 site. I'm not able to get the delta migration tool work correctly. What is the way to manually move those records over, perhaps which database tables to copy the records from?

Thank you!

Comment: If the Magento 2 site isn't in production yet, could you not just clear the M2 database and do a full migration from M1 again?

Comment: Hi, can you advise how i can clear the m2 database? i'm afraid it will also clear out the changes i have made in m2.

Comment: Easiest way is to just drop the database and run the installer again. If you're following good practices by putting your changes into modules, their setup scripts should create whatever tables are necessary. If you're talking about data changes, like CMS content, you can always back up that table first, then reset and reimport when you're done.

Comment: I saw you used the Magento database migration tool.
I'm looking to only export orders and client data from Magento 1.9.4.0 to Magento 2.2.7. Could you post the complete code of both files you modified? Br, Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I was able to migrate the customers and orders into the magento 2 again, without needing to use the delta migration step, nor empty the existing magento 2 orders/customers. I think it just overwrites the existing entries.

this is my config.xml data step looks like

```
        <steps mode="data">
            <step title="Data Integrity Step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
            </step>
    <!--        <step title="EAV Step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
                <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
                <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
            </step>  -->
            <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
                <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
                <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
            </step>
            <step title="Map Step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
                <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
                <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
            </step>
    <!--        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
                <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
                <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
            </step>
            <step title="Log Step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
                <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
                <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
            </step>
            <step title="Ratings Step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
                <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
                <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
            </step>
            <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
                <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
                <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
            </step>  -->
            <step title="OrderGrids Step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
                <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
                <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
            </step>
    <!--        <step title="Tier Price Step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
                <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
                <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
            </step>  -->
            <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
                <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
                <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
                <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
            </step>
            <!--<step title="PostProcessing Step">
                <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
            </step>-->
        </steps>
```

this is the map.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../map.xsd">
    <source>
        <document_rules>
            <ignore>
                <document>catalog_category*</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>catalog_compare*</document>
            </ignore>
             <ignore>
                <document>catalog_eav_attribute</document>
             </ignore>
             <ignore>
                <document>cataloginventory_stock*</document>
             </ignore>
             <ignore>
                <document>catalog_product_*</document>
             </ignore>
             <ignore>
                <document>catalog_category_*</document>
             </ignore>
```

Comment: Suppose in your m2 test order and customers created then during migration from m1 to m2 the m2 orders or customers will be any issue.
If in Magento 2 when order will be created then the Id of M1 and M2 will be same?

Comment: i didn't run into any issue, the magento 1 order# has 9 digits, and magento 2 default has 10 digits, but it's better to remove the test records before running the data migration tool

Comment: ok, so Order Ids will not be same as Magento 1 in Magento 2 due to default 9 in M1 and 10 in M2 ?
One more thing suppose we deleted test orders but the increment id jump already so i think we can set last incremental in table by which new order will look like in a sequence.