# Magento 2 : after migration why m2_cl tables are blank?

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

*I have upgraded M1 Database in Magento 2.3.3 .*

Migration succesfull but ***m2_cli*** tables are blank in M1 database .

***what is the reason for it ?***

***How we can do delta migration with m2_cli tables ?***

Comment: Did you find a solution ? We are facing the same problem.

Comment: Please check this post  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252716/how-to-manually-import-migrate-orders-customers-from-magento1-to-magento-2-dat  it is working for me .